# If $p, q$ are prime and $p > q$, then $p|(p – q)^p + q$, proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone give an '*elementary*' proof?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the binomial theorem, and $p$ trivially divides all but one of the terms from the expanded binomial. The remaining term, together with the "$+q$" is $-(q^p-q)$ which is divisible by $p$ according to Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is "elementary"...

Take the expression modulo p:
$$
\begin{align}
(p-q)^p+q &\equiv (-q)^p + q \\
&\equiv -q^p + q  \quad \text{since $p$ is odd}\\
&\equiv -q+q \quad \text{by Fermat's little theorem}\\
&\equiv 0 \end{align}
$$
So $p$ divides $(p-q)^p +q$.
(Note all equivalences are mod $p$.)

Note that the original information said that $p$ was a prime more than another prime, so that is how we know $p$ must be odd.

Note also that it's not necessary for $q$ to be prime for this to work.

Comment: $q$ is not a multiple of $p$ is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Actually $q$ can be any integer, and $p$ any prime.
If $a$ is any integer, then $a^p\equiv a~(\text{mod $p$})$.
Using this, the proof is simple: $(p-q)^p+q\equiv p-q+q\equiv 0~(\text{mod $p$})$ .